# How can I automate the advanced sharing settings in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to automate the advanced sharing settings in Windows. I'd like to do it using a batch script that may turn on the network discovery, file and printer sharing and turn off the password protected sharing for both Public and Home/Work profiles.

I have found some ways to turn on sharing, network discovery and others, but they don't make changes in the advanced sharing settings.

Edit: Here are some commands that I've tried to enable these settings:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=Yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="network discovery" new enable=Yes
```

But they don't enable anything in the advanced sharing settings.

Some help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `I have found multiple ways to turn on sharing, network discovery and others, but they don't make changes in the Advanced sharing settings.` Could you please edit your question and tell us what you've tried?

Comment: I have edited the question, Please take a look.

Comment: Well, I have been working on some project on windows platform that interacts with RaspberryPI. For that i need sharing settings enabled. Yes, I can easily go to Advanced sharing settings and enable it. Although it would be a one time step, but I want to automate this so whenever it's run somewhere else for the first time, the user may just have to run the script and in the backend all the sharing settings are enabled through a batch script. 

So,I need a batch script that may turn on the network discovery, file,printer sharing and turn off the password protected sharing for both profiles.

Comment: Did you get `No rules match ...` if you type the commands you mentioned? The group names of the rules are localized is your version of Windows English?

Comment: As far as I remember, there was no such message generated. Network discovery and file and printer sharing are by default enabled in Home profile i guess. It's password protected sharing that does not turn off by any command. I was wondering if there was any proper code to deal with all three options, because the above commands just allow these in the firewall.

Comment: So what is the output if you type these commands in your command prompt? There have to be any output at least that it was successful...

Comment: Updated 57 rules.
Ok.

<<This is what i get

Comment: Yes, it's an english version.

Comment: For me the commands you've mentioned are changing the settings in the advanced sharing settings. Should be the same for you...

Comment: Does any of these commands turn off the Password protected sharing option as well? I think no, can you turn that off through any command?

Comment: For that option it does not seem to be there a command. But I don't recommend to turn it off, as it is global for all shares. I don't think that a user want this to happen.

Comment: With [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) you can watch registry changes. You could observe what happens when you switch that option in the advanced sharing settings.

Comment: Well, if that's turned on, RaspberryPI, even being on the network will not be able to access shared folders of the windows platform without a password. And password is what I don't need in my application, once the folder is shared, it must be accessible to anyone on the network without a password.

I wonder why there's no command for it. But thanks a million for your help.

Comment: I'd give this ProcessMonitor a shot, Thanks a lot.